# Running Bash Shell Script continuously from boot at background. (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspberry-pi

So I want to run this script continuously in background. I was able to start it at boot and then run it, but it stops running after sometime. Whats wrong?

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myfirst
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:    
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: myfirst
# Description:       Speaker switch 
### END INIT INFO


echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction

while true;do
        ps cax | grep hairtunes > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        else
        echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        fi
        sleep 5
done

exit 0
```

Comment: how do you start it? from /etc/init.d/ ? rc.local? and what distro are you using?

Comment: From /etc/init.d I'm running raspbian.

Comment: Enable core dumps on Raspbian, when the process crashes you can analyze the dump and get more info what is wrong.

Comment: Change your first line to `#!/bin/bash`. When was `/sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value` last changed (who owns it) ?

Comment: /sys/class/gpio/gpio18 changes everytime the "hairtunes" process is detected. I'm sure it has nothing to do with that .

Comment: Try to use dmesg to see if the process was kernel killed for example because of lack of memory.

Comment: @ivanzg how do I use dmesg?

Comment: Grep the output of dmesg for string like "kill" --> "dmesg | grep -i kill", if the process was kernel killed the specified command should return lines that describe the process that was killed --> like "kernel ... killed process 4445 ..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't run while loop inside initscript. Init will kill long-running initscripts. You can extract all logic

```
echo "18" > /sys/class/gpio/export
echo "out" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/direction

while true;do
        ps cax | grep hairtunes > /dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "0" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        else
        echo "1" > /sys/class/gpio/gpio18/value
        fi
        sleep 5
done
```

into separate scrip and run it with `&` from initscipt. Like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          myfirst
# Required-Start:    $network
# Required-Stop:    
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: myfirst
# Description:       Speaker switch 
### END INIT INFO

case "$1" in
  start)
    /path/to/the/script/above/with/logic.sh &
    ;;
  stop)
    # you need to store pid to do this 
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

This should work. However, this isn't a best solution. The best one is to correctly demonize you process which is somewhat different topic.